# How to display the component only once?

Tags: dwt

Iam working on tridion templating and i have 2 components associated with the same component template.I want to display one at the top and one at the bottom.How should I do that? If i use the below code on the top of the page and the bottom of the page the same component is displayed 2 times on the top and 2 times at the bottom. Kindly let me know how to display this component only once at the top and once at the bottom?

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
              <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="ComponentTemplate == 'Scripts'" -->

                                <!-- start the code-->
                                @@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
                                <!-- end the code--> 

              <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
 <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in DWT, You can use `TemplateRepeatIndex` variable for that, It is actually a 0 based Index. So inside the loop 0 would be your first component and 1 would the second one.

Try something like below:

```
    <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
                  <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="ComponentTemplate == 'Scripts'" -->
    <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex == 0" -->
                                    <!-- start the code-->
                                    @@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
                                    <!-- end the code--> 
    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
                  <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
     <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->  

// Your Middle HTML goes here

    <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
                  <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="ComponentTemplate == 'Scripts'" -->
    <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex == 1" -->
                                    <!-- start the code-->
                                    @@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
                                    <!-- end the code--> 
    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
                  <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
     <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently your template is simply looping over all of the ComponentPresentations in the page (or more accurately, the list of ComponentPresentations call "Components". Typically you would develop a .Net based TBB which would first split or partition them into separate lists in the package according to your use case.

For more information and an example check out [PartitionComponentPresentations · TridionPractice/tridion-practice Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/PartitionComponentPresentations)

Comment: cant we just display the components that are added in the page using simple DWT code? Adding the condition like         <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex == 0" -->
 will help?

Comment: Yes, you could, but are your components *always* going to be the same position *everywhere* your template is used?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is easier way. We had similar issue and we did it by specifying exact tcmid of component and template in RenderComponentPresentation function as:

```
@@RenderComponentPresentation("${FooterID}","${PTStaticCCEmergencyFooterCTID}")@@
```

Basically, we extract footer id and footer template id via c# block, push them in package and then render explicitly.